# Managing split repositories in git

Tags: git

For example Zend has special folder for each component of their framework.

- https://github.com/zendframework/Component_ZendJson

How they manage this? What is the way to keep this repository up to date?

Comment: I think they use a package manager called composer: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Comment: Yes, sure they use. But how they split big repository into many small and keep them up to date?

Comment: If they did indeed had to split their git repo, they probably did something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository keeping things up to date is exactly what the package manager does.

Comment: But after split you have to keep updated splitted repository

Comment: Link is dead...